# use imaplib and oauth for connection with Gmail

Tags: python, django, oauth, imaplib

I want to use Oauth to connect to Gmail in Python. Right now I've got the xoauth.py script from Google ([link](http://code.google.com/p/google-mail-xoauth-tools/wiki/XoauthDotPyRunThrough)), and generating a token works all fine, but how can I then use that in another script? It's going to be in Django.

Right now my script logs in like this:

```
m = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL("imap.gmail.com")
m.login("example@gmail.com", "password")
```

But I want something more secure.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here's an example using the [`oauth2` module](https://github.com/simplegeo/python-oauth2) to authenticate using oauth, taken from the readme:

```
import oauth2 as oauth
import oauth2.clients.imap as imaplib

# Set up your Consumer and Token as per usual. Just like any other
# three-legged OAuth request.
consumer = oauth.Consumer('your_consumer_key', 'your_consumer_secret')
token = oauth.Token('your_users_3_legged_token', 
    'your_users_3_legged_token_secret')

# Setup the URL according to Google's XOAUTH implementation. Be sure
# to replace the email here with the appropriate email address that
# you wish to access.
url = "https://mail.google.com/mail/b/your_users_email@gmail.com/imap/"

conn = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.googlemail.com')
conn.debug = 4 

# This is the only thing in the API for impaplib.IMAP4_SSL that has 
# changed. You now authenticate with the URL, consumer, and token.
conn.authenticate(url, consumer, token)

# Once authenticated everything from the impalib.IMAP4_SSL class will 
# work as per usual without any modification to your code.
conn.select('INBOX')
print conn.list()
```

Quite a bit cleaner than using `xoauth`.

Comment: Hi Acorn, I am new to oauth2 and imaplib, and I have some questions now, can you answer them at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17976626/oauth2-and-imap-connection-with-gmail

Comment: I don't get where "your_users_3_legged_token" and "your_users_3_legged_token_secret" come from :/

Answer (score 8):

Google has a good example code to do [OAuth2 and IMAP](https://github.com/google/gmail-oauth2-tools/wiki/OAuth2DotPyRunThrough). Also make sure that your scope is
correct.

```
'scope': 'https://mail.google.com/'
'access_type': 'offline'
```

Below is from the code sample in google example

```
import base64
import imaplib

my_email = "xyz@gmail.com"
access_token = ""    #Oauth2 access token

auth_string = GenerateOAuth2String(my_email, access_token, base64_encode=False)
TestImapAuthentication(my_email, auth_string)


def TestImapAuthentication(user, auth_string):
  """Authenticates to IMAP with the given auth_string.

  Prints a debug trace of the attempted IMAP connection.

  Args:
    user: The Gmail username (full email address)
    auth_string: A valid OAuth2 string, as returned by GenerateOAuth2String.
        Must not be base64-encoded, since imaplib does its own base64-encoding.
  """
  print
  imap_conn = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')
  imap_conn.debug = 4
  imap_conn.authenticate('XOAUTH2', lambda x: auth_string)
  imap_conn.select('INBOX')


def GenerateOAuth2String(username, access_token, base64_encode=True):
  """Generates an IMAP OAuth2 authentication string.

  See https://developers.google.com/google-apps/gmail/oauth2_overview

  Args:
    username: the username (email address) of the account to authenticate
    access_token: An OAuth2 access token.
    base64_encode: Whether to base64-encode the output.

  Returns:
    The SASL argument for the OAuth2 mechanism.
  """
  auth_string = 'user=%s\1auth=Bearer %s\1\1' % (username, access_token)
  if base64_encode:
    auth_string = base64.b64encode(auth_string)
  return auth_string
```

Comment: Google provide OAuth 1 & 2 examples. Their OAuth 1 API is depreciated and I can't get it working with django-social-auth. The above which is OAuth 2 works fine with django-social-auth.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example of connecting to IMAP using routines present in Google's `xoauth.py`.  It'll output some debug information, so you'll probably want to switch to using the [oauth](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/oauth) package for a real application.  At least this should get you started:

```
import imaplib
import random
import time

import xoauth

MY_EMAIL = 'xxx@gmail.com'
MY_TOKEN = # your token
MY_SECRET = # your secret

def connect():
    nonce = str(random.randrange(2**64 - 1))
    timestamp = str(int(time.time()))

    consumer = xoauth.OAuthEntity('anonymous', 'anonymous')
    access = xoauth.OAuthEntity(MY_TOKEN, MY_SECRET)
    token = xoauth.GenerateXOauthString(
        consumer, access, MY_EMAIL, 'imap', MY_EMAIL, nonce, timestamp)

    imap_conn = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.googlemail.com')
    imap_conn.authenticate('XOAUTH', lambda x: token)
    imap_conn.select('INBOX')

    return imap_conn

connect()
```

Comment: This works indeed, thanks. How would I do it with the oauth package?

Comment: You could continue using xoauth as-is if you can tolerate the print statements, or just rip them out of your local copy. I haven't personally used oauth but I imagine the api is similar. There is an example in the oauth repository: [oauth client example](http://oauth.googlecode.com/svn/code/python/oauth/example/client.py)