# Authenticating with imaplib.IMAP4 and OAuth without OAuth2

Tags: python, oauth, web.py, imaplib, rauth

I'm using web.py to build a simple server that learns on a user's gmail messages. I've gone through the OAuth flow using the [rauth](https://rauth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/#oauth-2-0-services) library and I now have the access token. I now want to use [imaplib](http://docs.python.org/2/library/imaplib.html) to pull down the messages for processing. However, it's extremely unclear to me how I use the IMAP4.authenticate method. From the documentation:

> Authenticate command — requires response processing.
>
> mechanism specifies which authentication mechanism is to be used - it should appear in the nstance variable capabilities in the form AUTH=mechanism.
>
> authobject must be a callable object:
>
> data = authobject(response)
> It will be called to process server continuation responses. It should return data that will be encoded and sent to server. It should return None if the client abort response * should be sent instead.

All of the [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5193707/use-imaplib-and-oauth-for-connection-with-gmail) I can find online doing this use the authenticate method of the oauth2 library or xoauth library, but I've read that oauth2 is deprecated and xoauth is not fit for production. What's the move here? What's the library for my job?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The library I wanted is Google's new [OAuth2 python library](http://code.google.com/p/google-mail-oauth2-tools/wiki/OAuth2DotPyRunThrough). I was confused by naming because oauth2-python, which is deprecated, is also 'import oauth2'. With their library it's dead simple cause they have a function called GenerateOAuth2String which just takes an email and a token and generates something you can pass write to imaplib, which they demo in the function TestImapAuthentication. perfect.