# Use custom domain for flask app with Google authenticated login

Tags: python

I have built a flask web application that makes use of Google's authenticated login to authenticate users. I currently have it running on localhost `127.0.0.1:5000` however I would like to point a custom domain name to it that I would like to purchase.

I have used custom domains with Flask applications before, I'm just not sure how to do it with this. I'm confused as to what I would do with my oauth callback.

My callback is set to `http://127.0.0.1:5000/authorized` in my Google oauth client credentials. I don't think it would just be as easy as running the app on `0.0.0.0`.

I would need to be able to match the flask routes to the domain. i.e be able to access `www.mydomain.com/authorized`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this just now!

I went through my DNS settings of my domain and pointed the DNS A record to the IP address that my flask application is running on.

Previously, I was using a redirect on the domain, which was not working.