# connect to Outlook server using imap has error b'LOGIN failed.'

Tags: python, smtp, office365, imap, two-factor-authentication

I have a Microsoft account, that is an enterprise account, and I want to use IMAP in Python to connect to the Outlook server, port 993. I got this error after running ('b'LOGIN failed.''). I also used app passwords or disabled all 2FA, still get this error. 
Please assist me if you are familiar with this situation.

Here is my code

```py
import imaplib
import email
from email.header import decode_header
import webbrowser
import os
import rds_config

# account credentials
username = "myname@enterprise.microsoft.com"
password = "mypassword or app-password"
imap_server = 'outlook.office365.com'

# create an IMAP4 class with SSL 
imap = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(imap_server, port=993)
# authenticate
imap.login(username, password)

# status, messages = imap.select('"Sent Items"')
status, messages = imap.select('INBOX')
messages = int(messages[0])
```

Here is the error:

```bash
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\Users\Among\Desktop\Code\UpWork\rodney_projects\lambda_sync_email_to_MYSQL\source\test.ipynb Cell 15 in <cell line: 26>()
     24 imap = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(imap_server, port=993)
     25 # authenticate
---> 26 imap.login(username, password)
     28 # status, messages = imap.select('"Sent Items"')
     29 status, messages = imap.select('INBOX')

File c:\Users\Among\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\imaplib.py:612, in IMAP4.login(self, user, password)
    610 typ, dat = self._simple_command('LOGIN', user, self._quote(password))
    611 if typ != 'OK':
--> 612     raise self.error(dat[-1])
    613 self.state = 'AUTH'
    614 return typ, dat

error: b'LOGIN failed.'
```

Comment: try different port 587 & server name `smtp.office365.com`

Comment: You cannot use passwords with Office365 servers anymore.

Comment: How about using app password on Microsoft?

Comment: I tried to change port to 587 & server name to smtp.office365.com but still not work.

Comment: Did you set up the service principal? I have a note on it on my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75264107/authenticate-with-exchange-to-access-email-inbox-with-imaplib/75264108#75264108

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use strong authentification now. Microsoft disabled the Basic Auth :
https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/exchange-team-blog/basic-authentication-deprecation-in-exchange-online-september/ba-p/3609437

See this topic for IMAP with XOAUTH :
[Use IMAP with XOAUTH2 and MS365 Application permissions to authenticate IMAP for a user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73368376/use-imap-with-xoauth2-and-ms365-application-permissions-to-authenticate-imap-for)